# How to make Oban run more frequently than once in a minute?

Tags: cron, elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-oban

I'm using Oban for the ongoing tasks.

```
# .....
    {Oban.Plugins.Cron,
     crontab: [
       {"* * * * *", MyApp.Workers.W1},
       {"* * * * *", MyApp.Workers.W2},
     ]},
```

I now need to run `W1` and `W2` more frequently that every minute - around once in every 10...30 seconds. Since cron doesn't support higher frequency than 1/min, how would I get around this limitation? Preferably without hacks, unless absolutely necessary.

I don't consider switching from Oban to other library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe `Oban.Plugins.Cron` supports granularity finer than one minute, by glancing at [the current code](https://github.com/sorentwo/oban/blob/0b427431a0e90fb3eb065a28d1e5bb6bb5f56312/lib/oban/plugins/cron.ex).

One way you could do this is by having a process (like a GenServer) in your application that uses [`Process.send_after/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Process.html#send_after/3) or [`:timer.send_interval/2`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html#send_interval-2) to periodically queue the Oban jobs you want. This is essentially what `Oban.Plugins.Cron` is doing. You'll probably want to pay attention to making sure the jobs are unique ([documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/oban/2.14.1/Oban.html#module-unique-jobs)).

Some very simplified code:

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.Scheduler do
  use GenServer

  def start_link(_) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, :no_args)
  end

  @impl true
  def init(:no_args) do
    :timer.send_interval(:timer.seconds(30), {:schedule_job, MyApp.Workers.W1, 30})
    :timer.send_interval(:timer.seconds(20), {:schedule_job, MyApp.Workers.W2, 20})
    {:ok, :no_state}
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_info({:schedule_job, worker, unique_seconds}, state) do
    %{my: :params}
    |> Oban.Job.new(worker: worker, unique: [period: unique_seconds])
    |> Oban.insert!()

    {:noreply, state}
  end
end
```

Comment: But then I'll have to turn off the standard mechanism by which Oban will insert W1 and W2 jobs, right?  Remove these 2 lines from config `{"* * * * *", MyApp.Workers.W1},` and `{"* * * * *", MyApp.Workers.W2},`?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I should have made that clear, my bad 